# How to get base image id with the DigitalOcean API?

Tags: image, deployment, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy a box standard Ubuntu 14.04 image in ams1 using the api service. However, so far I have not been able to locate the appropriate id.

I have tried this using

```
curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer b7d03a6947b217efb6f3ec3bd3504582' "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/images?page=1&per_page=1"
```

from https://developers.digitalocean.com/#list-all-application-images

and similary via dopy (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dopy)

It outputs all the fancy installations like MEAN on Ubuntu, Dokku on Ubuntu 14.04, etc, but not the base distribution for Ubuntu 14.04. Anyone knows how to get this?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the IDs are the same for all accounts, but here we go.

https://api.digitalocean.com/images/?client_id=xxx&api_key=xxx

**14.04 x32**

```
{"id":6918735,"name":"14.04 x32","slug":"ubuntu-14-04-x32","distribution":"Ubuntu","public":true,"regions":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],"region_slugs":["nyc1","ams1","sfo1","nyc2","ams2","sgp1","lon1","nyc3","ams3"]}
```

**14.04 x64**

```
{"id":6918990,"name":"14.04 x64","slug":"ubuntu-14-04-x64","distribution":"Ubuntu","public":true,"regions":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],"region_slugs":["nyc1","ams1","sfo1","nyc2","ams2","sgp1","lon1","nyc3","ams3"]}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$TOKEN'' \    
    "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/images?page=1&per_page=1"
```

should return the base distributions as well. Note that the results are paginated. Increase the `per_page` parameter to see more in a single query. You can also filter specifically on '[applications](https://developers.digitalocean.com/v2/#list-all-application-images)' or  '[distribution](https://developers.digitalocean.com/v2/#list-all-distribution-images)' using the `type` parameter. So to only retrieve the base images, use:

```
curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer '$TOKEN'' \
    "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/images?per_page=100&type=distribution"
```

Also, you'll generally want to use the image's `slug` when launching a droplet. The `id` will change if there is an update to the image, but the `slug` is guaranteed to be stable.

*Full-disclosure, among other things, I'm a Community Manager at Digitalocean*